# Edit the webhook URL after envelope creation

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to edit the webhook url after the envelope has already been created?
During the envelope creation I create the webhook url using:

```
$event_notification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EventNotification();
$event_notification->setUrl("https://mywebhooks.com/docusign/index.php");

$envelope_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelope_definition->setEventNotification($event_notification);
```

Everything works and it's hitting the url as expected.

However, recently we have added authentication to our webhook url and want to add a GET param to the url so we can validate it when we get hit by this call.

So the updated URL is set to `$event_notification->setUrl("https://mywebhooks.com/docusign/index.php?api_key=docusign_webhook_key");` but now the old envelopes that have already been created without this param will hit our system and not get authenticated because it's missing the param.

Is there any way to update the URL's of the already created envelopes?

(There is a way to hardcode the webhook url in the console - https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-custom-connect-configuration-htm. That works fine when i add it there. But it then gets hits twice and will cause failures on our end.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it looks like in-flight envelopes cannot have their EventNotifications changed.